# Neverwinter - question about Barrabus the Grey

Tags: forgotten-realms

Artemis Entreri is now Barrabus the Grey. In which book did he become Barrabus the Grey? I read Transitions series already. Am I missing a series?

Answer (score 4):

If you've read the [Sellswords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sellswords) series ([*Servant of the Shard*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servant_of_the_Shard), [*Promise of the Witch King*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promise_of_the_Witch_King), [*Road of the Patriarchs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_of_the_Patriarch)), then you should be caught up.

I'm assuming you're reading the [*Neverwinter Saga*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neverwinter_Saga) now. I'm not aware of a separate story that details how Artemis winds up in the situation he's found in there. I suspect that, as you work your way through those books, more details will become clear.

Comment: Since this involves stories I haven't read yet, I found the correct spelling of "Barrabus" in the Artemis Entreri Wikipedia entry, and was able to narrow this down from there. (I've read the Sellswords books, and the Transitions series is next on my list for Drizzt, et al).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have read the sellsword series. I do hope they go into greater detail about how he became apart of the shadowvar eventually. In the book Neverwinter Artemis (excuse me if i misspell) said Jarlaxel betrade him to the shadowvar. I didn't remember ever reading that so i thought i may have missed a series somewhere down the line. I guess I'll find out later. Again thank you.

Answer (score 4):

There is a short story I listened to from a collection of *Drizzt* short stories called *The Collected Stories, The Legend of Drizzt* by Salvatore on Audible.

One of them was about Artemis and Jarlaxle. During the story, Artemis kills a Shadovar with his dagger (the one that sucks out the victims life source and transfers that energy to Artemis). After the kill, Jarlaxle comments that Artemis now has a slightly gray color to his skin.